# Log4net output to My Documents

Tags: c#, log4net

In our C# app, we write files to `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments)`. Our log4net logfile should go there too, so we've defined `application.conf` as follows:

```
<appender name="LogFile" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
  <appendToFile value="true"/>
  <file value="%USERPROFILE%\My Documents\MyApp\log.txt"/>
  ...snip...
</appender>
```

This works, until we run in on a PC which has a non-English Windows. Because then, `SpecialFolder.MyDocuments` points to the folder `Mijn Documenten`, while the log still goes to `My Documents`. Confusion ensues, because now our files are in two places.

I want to write my log to the "real" My Documents folder. How do I do this?

- I tried to find an environment variable like `%USERPROFILE%`, but there doesn't seem to exist one for My Documents.
- There's a registry key that defines the true location of My Documents but it's not accessible from `application.conf`.
- I tried to override the `File` parameter of my appender programmatically, like this:

  ```
  public static void ConfigureLogger()
  {
      XmlConfigurator.Configure();

      Hierarchy hierarchy = (Hierarchy)log4net.LogManager.GetRepository();
      foreach (var appender in hierarchy.Root.Appenders)
      {
          if (appender is FileAppender)
          {
              var fileAppender = appender as FileAppender;
              var logDirectory = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments), "MyApp");
              var pathElements = fileAppender.File.Split(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar);
              var logFileName = pathElements.Last();
              var fullLogFilePath = Path.Combine(logDirectory, logFileName);
              fileAppender.File = fullLogFilePath;
          }
      }
  }
  ```

  This doesn't work either: when I inspect the internals of my logger, the `File` property happily reports `Mijn Documenten`, but in the mean time the logs still go to `My Documents`.

I'm running out of ideas!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Change the line

```
<file value="%USERPROFILE%\My Documents\MyApp\log.txt"/>
```

to

```
<file type="log4net.Util.PatternString" value="%envFolderPath{MyDocuments}\MyApp\log.txt" />
```

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answer is out of date.

You should now use:

```
<file value="${UserProfile}\Documents\log-messages.log" />
```

(This should work even on Windows 7, where "Documents" is referred to by the alias "My Documents".)

`${UserProfile}` will map to C:\Users[UserName], even if you don't see this variable explicitly defined in your environment variable list.

Comment: Is this still working? In my case I get `${UserProfile}` folder created in the `bin` folder.

Answer (score 1):

There seem to be at least 2 approaches. The simplest is kind of a hack:

1. Specify a custom environment variable to indicate the root path in you log4net config:

   `<file value="%MYAPP_USER_ROOTFOLDER%\MyApp\log.txt"/>`
2. At startup, before initializing logging, set this environment variable value:

   `Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("MYAPP_USER_ROOTFOLDER", Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments));`

The more complicated but recommended approach is explained here: http://marc.info/?l=log4net-user&m=110142086820117&w=2 and here http://ziqbalbh.com/articles/log4net-another-way-to-change-log-file-location-on-runtime/