# C# (WPF) - Getting Library folder paths in App.config

Tags: c#, wpf, log4net, app-config

I'm looking to place some logfiles in the user's documents folder. The log path for my log4net logger is configured in the App.config XML, so I can't programmatically determine the path using the usual methods. Can the My Documents library be accessed by an environment variable, like pre-Windows 7 documents folders?

Comment: So do you want to set the app.config entry to the current logged in users my documents folder?

Comment: And also another question: which logger are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
string path = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
```

**Edit**

If you logging other than log4net. You need not store the log file path in the app.config in that case. because whatever you write in app.config you will end up overriding it. So it will be misleading and useless. If you want to pickup the MyDocuments location my suggestion is to fetch it in the code and wire it up with your logging module.

If you are using log4netuse the suggestion by @derpirscher - [Log4net output to My Documents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18364691/log4net-output-to-my-documents)

Comment: Can't run code in the app.config XML.

Comment: couldn't understand the question. Do you want to modify app.config?

Comment: Got it now! are you using log4net?

Comment: The path is stored in app.config. And yes, this is for log4net.

Comment: Maybe this answer will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18364691/log4net-output-to-my-documents

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at `Environment.GetFolderPath` ([MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14tx8hby(v=vs.110).aspx))

Now, as you clarified it's for log4net have a look at the following question

[Log4net output to My Documents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18364691/log4net-output-to-my-documents)

Comment: Still can't run code in appconfig.xml, where the path is set.